# How to get horizontal scroll in JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

I have 2 issue that i need to ask, 1st how to get the horizontal scroll for my JTable, currently it shrink all the columns which is not readable at all. I have 20 columns to show in a Table.

2nd, how to adjust my table height width maximum to my screen size.

my current code is

```
Container cp = getContentPane();

            ConnectionDB con = new ConnectionDB();
            tableModel = con.getRecord(DEFAULT_QUERY);

    table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(900, 500));

    table.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Books:"));
    cp.add("Center", centerPanel);
```

Kindly help me in it, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For horizontal scroll, use `JScrollPane`

Comment: @johnchen902, this is JScrollPane. how to get scoll?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What do you mean by the maximum size? If you add your `ScrollPanel` to the center of the `BorderLayout` it should automatically resize and the maximum size of a JFrame normally is the screen size.

Comment: I am adding JDesktopPane in my Container center and JDesktopPane is getting object of another class where table is setting up into JScrollPane and it is setting up in another Container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To prevent that all columns are resized to the `ScrollPane` size you can disable the auto resize:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Adding your `ScrollPane` to the center of the `BorderLayout` should set the maximum size to the screen size, because normally the JFrame can't become bigger.

To set the size of the `ScrollPane`s ViewPort to the screen size you can use the awt `Toolkit`.

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
```

Comment: Yeah i got horizontal scroll, but how to get maximum size to the screen size for my ScrollPane?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it exactly. Should the ScrollPane be always at it's maximum size or is it normally smaller and the maximum is just the maximal possible size? How is it now and how should it be? Could you add a screenshot or a sketch of the current state and describe how it should be?

Comment: when i set table dimensions like this "table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 500));" it extends the size according to dimensions, but i want it to be maximum to my screen size, to make it bit more clear, my table is in JScrollPane and JScrollPane is in a container which is getting the contentpane.

Comment: i solved my problem with this code "Toolkit toolkit =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
                Dimension dim = toolkit.getScreenSize();
                table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(dim.width,dim.height));"

Comment: Ah okay, now I see what you wanted. I will add your solution to my answer so it is easyer to find. (You can just set `dim` to your ViewPort size. You do not have to fetch the Dimension and then create a new Dimension with its values, just use the first :D)

Answer (score 1):

Add your `JTable` inside `JScrollPane` and set for scrollbars.

```
new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Code sample for `JTable` to fit the screen size

```
public class TestJTableFitsScreenWidth {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(
                        new String[][]{
                            new String[] {"A", "B", "D"},
                            new String[] {"D", "E", "F"}
                        },
                        new String[] {"col1", "col2", "col3"});
                JTable table = new JTable(dtm);
                table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                f.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.pack();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working, i modified my 4th last line with yours, what am doing wrong?

Comment: `table.setHorizontalScrollEnabled(true);` try this

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
        Dimension d = new Dimension(900, 800);
        tbl_transaction.setAutoResizeMode(tbl_transaction.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        tbl_transaction.setPreferredSize(d);
        tbl_transaction.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);
```